# SQL Server is stripping out unicode in equals query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone explain why when I run:

```
select * from (select N'someString' as id)_id where _id.id = N'someString'
```

in sql server I get a result of someString

I am not doing a like comparison, and cannot find anything in the documentation to explain this behaviour, I need an exact match or I need validation rules in my server to exclude any character that behaves like this.

DB is using collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS if this has any impact?

Comment: Can you give a real example with the output of SQL Server and your expected output so we can understand the issue further.

Comment: If you're not using a binary collation, SQL Server applies various rules which yes, do result in it being "blind" to certain characters or treating large number of distinct characters/sequences as being equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were probably in the right track. The collation will define how the comparison is made. Here's one option that could help you solve your problem.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'someString'),
            (N'someString'),
            (N'someString'),
            (N'someString'),
            (N'somestring')) V(S)
WHERE S = N'someString' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_WS
```

Collation is described as `Latin1-General-100, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, kanatype-sensitive, width-sensitive`

Comment: Yes, it was the collecation and this one seems to do the tric, thank you

Comment: I've seen seen `Latin1-General-100` being referred to as the new utf8 collation which handles utf8 characters properly

Comment: @AntonPiatek if you want "true" UTF-8 support on SQL Server, you want the UTF-8 collations added in SQL Server 2019. [Introducing UTF-8 support in SQL Server 2019 preview](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/12/18/introducing-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-preview/)

Comment: @AntonPiatek this has nothing to do with UTF8, and `Latin1-General-100` is definitely not UTF8, it's the base Latin1 collation. UTF16 and UTF8 can represent the same characters. *Collations* have nothing to do with encodings, they define how characters are sorted and which characters are considered equals and which shouldn't be considered at all (hense the _WS), because they may be considered diacritics

Comment: The collation doesn't have to be Kana-sensitive. `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_WS` will also work

Answer (score 8):

Appears that, regardless of it's position, the poo emoji is skipped. For example the below returns every row:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'someString'),
            (N'someString'),
            (N'someString'),
            (N'someString')) V(S)
WHERE S = N'someString';
```

If you use a binary collation, this doesn't happen:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'someString'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN),
            (N'someString'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN),
            (N'someString'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN),
            (N'someString'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN)) V(S)
WHERE S = N'someString';
```

If SQL Server dealing with these unicode characters/emoji is important, then a binary collation will likely be your best choice.

Comment: Unfortunatly we need case insensitivity, any ideas?