# Differentiate Exponents in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

In SQL Server 2017 (14.0.2)

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE expTest
(
    someNumbers [NVARCHAR](10) NULL
)
```

And let's say you populate the table with some values:

```
INSERT INTO expTest VALUES('²', '2')
```

Why does the following SELECT return both rows?

```
SELECT * 
FROM expTest 
WHERE someNumbers = '2'
```

Shouldn't `nvarchar` realize that '²' is unicode, while '2' is a separate value? How (without using the UNICODE() function) could I identify this data as being nonequivalent?

Comment: What is your collation setting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server is stripping out unicode in equals query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456344/sql-server-is-stripping-out-unicode-in-equals-query)

Comment: For instance, you're not using UNICODE strings, but the problem comes from the collation that you're using.

Comment: You seem to have a syntax error in your insert statement.@christopher

Comment: @DaleBurrell SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=610a7d1d099b7b5d63c1482bb6a133e6) is a db<>fiddle.  This shows the following:

- Your observation is true even when the values are entered as national character set constants.
- The "ASCII" versions of the characters are actually different.
- The problem goes away with a case-sensitive collation.

I think the exponent is just being treated as a different "case" of the number, so they are considered the same in a case-insensitive collation.

The comparison is what you expect with a case-sensitive collation.